# How can I allow only selected Lambdas to invalidate the API-Gateway Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, cache-control

I’m using an AWS API-Gateway with a lambda as the endpoint to write data into a dynamoDB table. Another lambda which is invoked from the same API (different resource) returns this data. I have enabled the API Cache since I do not want the lambda to get the same data every time.

I have 2 lambdas which should be able to invalidate this cache. One to just remove it and the other is the one I mentioned before which should invalidate the cache when new data is written into the table.

I want to prevent everything else from invalidating this cache. I was following this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#invalidate-method-caching) and assigned the mentioned policy to the lambdas, but how do I prevent everything else from invalidating this cache by sending the `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header?

I understood the article above as if i can either use 'require authorization' or use the policy. But I can still invalidate the cache by just sending a request via postman with the Cache-Control header.

Can somebody tell me what I’m misunderstanding here?

This is the policy I assigned to the 2 lambda roles:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:InvalidateCache"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/GET/resource-path-specifier"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to provide **exact** details of your API setup, cache policies and more. Its not clear what you did and why it does not work.

Comment: @Marcin i'm rather new to AWS. What kind of details do u need of the API? 
I added the policy I assigned to the 2 lambda roles to my main post.

Comment: @Marcin The Api i'm talking about has 3 resources with 1 method each ( 1x GET and 2x POST). I have not set up an API authorization. The GET Method should be usable for anybody but the cache should only be invalidated by the 2 lambdas which are invoked by the resources with the POST method.